# Custom header height avoiding CSS

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, header, webix

Is there a way to set a custom header height avoiding CSS in Webix? 
When I redefine classes such as `webix_ss_header` and `webix_hcell` the height of a layout changes according to the modification that I've made. 
For example:

```
.webix_hcell {
    line-height:20px !important;
    height:20px !important;    
}
.webix_ss_header {
    height:20px !important;  
}
```

The above code causes [**following issues**](http://webix.com/snippet/b1187841):

1. Header of the vertical scrollbar doesn't adjust to others and requires another CSS class;
2. In the bottom appears a space that corresponds to the difference between the default and the custom height of the header. Herewith the vertical scrollbar rendering as usual.

As you can see, it affects the position of the underneath content, the footer and the scrollbar. How can I overcome this?

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you're talking about. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @thedp ok! the question has been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to set the custom height to the header:

1 - `headerRowHeight` property

```
  view:"datatable",   
  headerRowHeight:20,
```

2 - `height` for the one of headers

```
columns:[  
    { id:"title",   header:{text:"", height:20} ,width:250},
]
```

Your snippet:
http://webix.com/snippet/6519b63d